# Get current URL arguments inside ajax callback?

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I have created custom module called 'mymodule'.

In this URL **localhost/es/mymodule/name/1/2/3**, I have this field:

```
$form['name'] = array(
  '#title' => t('Enter name'),
  ...
  '#ajax' => array(
    'event' => 'blur',
    'callback' => 'mymodule_ajax_callback',
    'wrapper' => 'my-wrapper',
    'method' => 'replace',
  ),
  ...
);
```

My ajax callback is successfully called:

```
function mymodule_ajax_callback($form, &$form_state) {
  ...
  return ...
}
```

However, inside 'mymodule_ajax_callback', I need to get the current URL arguments of the page such that `arg(1) = 'name'`, `arg(2) = 1`, `arg(3) = 2`, and so on.

By nature, Drupal uses the URL **system/ajax** so calling `arg(N)` does not work as I need it to be.

How to get the current URL arguments using `arg()` inside the ajax callback?

---

EDIT 1:

I thought of using `$_SESSION[...] = arg(1); $_SESSION[...] = arg(2); ...` on my form and calling the session variables on my ajax callback. But I am looking for a better way without using session but only using drupal methods if available.

Comment: If the current URL arguments were applied by form submition (by applying some exposed filters for example) you can easy get all of them from `$_GET` as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The arguments passed to the page callback are saved in `$form_state['build_info']['args']`, with the exception of the form ID.

If you use the following definition for the menu item, you would get them there. (Replace `'form ID`' with the form builder ID.)

```
$item['name/%/%/%'] = array(
  // …

  'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
  'page arguments' => array('form ID', 1, 2, 3),

  // …
);
```

#### References

- [drupal_get_form()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_get_form/7)
- [drupal_build_form()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_build_form/7)

Answer (score 1):

Create the hidden field in the form & store the current url as below:

```
$current_url = arg(1);
$form['current_url'] = array('#type' => 'hidden', '#value' => $current_url);
```

And that than you can access the above hidden field in the ajax callback as `$form_state['values']['current_url']`

The above method worked for me.

Comment: There is no need to use a hidden field, since the value doesn't need to be passed to the browser.

Comment: Yeah right, and thanks for providing the better solution!!

Answer (score 0):

This is the trick I use for the OpenLayers module:

`function openlayers_ui_admin_settings($form, &$form_state) { 
  $form['openlayers_default_map'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('OpenLayers Default Map'),
    '#description' => t('This is the default map that will be used
      in cases where one is not defined.  It will also be used as
      the default when creating new maps.'),
    '#options' => $options,
    '#default_value' => variable_get('openlayers_default_map', 'map1'),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => '_ajax_reload_default_map',
      'method' => 'replace',
      'wrapper' => 'default_map_ajax',
      'effect' => 'fade'
  );
  $form['current_path'] = array('#type' => 'value', '#value' => current_path());
  return system_settings_form($form);
}
function _ajax_reload_default_map($form, &$form_state) {
  $_SESSION['current_path'] = $form_state['input']['current_path'];
  $map = openlayers_object_load('map', $form_state['values']['openlayers_default_map']);
  $form['default_map']['map'] = array(
    '#markup' => openlayers_render_map($map)
  );;
  return $form['default_map'];
}`

Instead of using `$form_state['values']`, I use `$form_state['input']`, it doesn't get updated through the AJAX calls and the current path remains correct.